# Codeception Acceptance Testing

Tags: testing, codeception, acceptance-testing

If you have a test in which before the acceptance test is run you want the database changed can you do it? I don't think it's possible because I can't find a way to pass data to the amOnPage call since that is basically just opening a browser to that URL and starting a new session which inherently means it is completely disconnected from the command I run to start the test in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :).

Comment: You can use Db module to make changes to database. https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db